# Does PHP 7 have a way to crash on non-existing class when using the `MyClass::class` notation?

Tags: php-7

A basic use case would be calling `MyEventListener::class` without having imported `use MyNamespace\MyEventListener`. The result would be a broken piece of code that's relatively hard to debug.

Does PHP 7 provide a directive to crash instead of returning the class name if no class exists? For example:

After calling `use Foo\Bar;`, `Bar::class` would return `'Foo\Bar'`.

But if no import statement, PHP returns `'Bar'`, even though the class doesn't exist, not even in the global namespace.

Can I make it crash somehow?

Comment: Check out the [`Reflection` book](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

Answer (score 4):

The thing you need to keep in mind is that `use Foo\Bar;` is not "importing" anything. It is telling the compiler: when I say "Bar" I mean `Bar` from the namespace `Foo`.

`Bar::class` is substituted blindly with the string "Foo\Bar". It isn't checking anything.

Until you attempt to instantiate or interact with a class it will not check to see if it exists. That said, it does not throw an `Exception`, it throws an `Error`:

```
// this doesn't exist!
use Foo/Bar;

try {
    $instanceOfBar = new Bar();
}
catch (Error $e) {
    // catching an Exception will not work
    // Throwable or Error will work
}
```

You can trap and check for non-existent classes at run time, but until you do it will happily toss around strings referring to classes that don't exist.

This is a blessing in the case of Laravel's IoC container and autoloader that abuses this to alias classes as convenient top-level objects. A curse, if you were expecting PHP to throw a fuss on `::class` not existing.

---

**Update:**
My suggestion for anyone worried about this problem is to use [PHPStan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan) in your testing pipeline. It prevents a lot of mistakes, and unlike `php -l` it will catch if you were to try and interact with a non-existent class.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you're going to get a nice error message when you try to instantiate a class that cannot be found through autoloading or explicitly added.

If you want to check if the class exists, first, try this:

```
$classOutsideNamespaceExists = class_exists('Bar');
$classInsideNameSpaceExists = class_exists('\\Foo\\Bar'));
```

Or you could try this syntax available since PHP 5.5:

`class_exists(MyClass::class)`

Finally, you can always use the tried and true method of a try-catch block.

```
try {
 $instanceOfMyClass = new MyClass();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  // conclude the class does not exist and handle accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> PhpStorm proposes and generates hints like `ArrayShape`, `Pure`, etc.
>
> But automatically it is adding
>
> `php use JetBrains\PhpStorm\ArrayShape;`
>
> or another.
>
> Is not that dangerous that on some production server I will get error
> 'Class JetBrains\PhpStorm\ArrayShape not found'?

(c)LazyOne:

1. Well, just use composer require --dev jetbrains/phpstorm-attributes to add such classes to your project. See github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-attributes
2. As long as instance of such a class is not actually gets instantiated (created) you should have no error because use statement is just a declaration.